# Redirect root path to child in react-router 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to force redirect the exact root path `/` to a child path (we have several modules and the root will just direct you to the first one, there's nothing to show at the actual root).

However I can't find any examples for the root path, and trying other approaches (with `Navigation to` just trigger an infinite loop.

```
<Route element={<Navigate replace to='/module/submodule' />} path='/'>
  <Route element={<Module />} handle={{ crumb: (): string => 'Module' }} path='module'>
    <Route element={<Submodule />} handle={{ crumb: (): string => 'Submodule' }} path='submodule' />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

I need to redirect `/` to `/module/submodule`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use an index route.

```
<Route path='/'>
  <Route element={<Navigate replace to='/module/submodule' />} index />
  <Route element={<Module />} handle={{ crumb: (): string => 'Module' }} path='module'>
    <Route element={<Submodule />} handle={{ crumb: (): string => 'Submodule' }} path='submodule' />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this correct for `react-router-dom:6.15.0`?

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <App />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
        children: [
            {
                index: true,
                element: <Navigate replace to='/projects' />,
            },
            {
                path: '/projects',
                element: <ProjectsPage />,
            },
        ],
    },
])
```

Comment: This is how I did it and I can confirm, this works. If there are caveats to this approach, I have not yet come across those.

Answer (score 1):

Move the redirect into a nested "catch-all" route. Anything not matched by any route will be redirected to `"/module/submodule"`.

```
<Route path="/">
  <Route
    path="module"
    element={<Module />}
    handle={{ crumb: (): string => 'Module' }}
  >
    <Route
      path="submodule"
      element={<Submodule />}
      handle={{ crumb: (): string => 'Submodule' }}
    />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/module/submodule" />} />
</Route>
```